# VisualStudio - Fatal error LNK1168: cannot open myfile.exe for writing

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio, compiler-errors

Sometime, while I try to compile my project, VisualStudio show me this error:

> **1>LINK : fatal error LNK1168: cannot open C:\Path\myfile.exe for writing**

and It not allowes me to compile the project.

It seems that `myfile.exe` is open and running in background yet, although I closed it. I opened Win TaskManager but the file is not shown in the list of process running.

This error persists and the only solution I found is reboot the system, but it's a tedious way that give me crazy because this error recurs often.

Some ideas to resolve it? Someone had the same error before?

Comment: Probably a virus scanner interfering

Comment: Is the process still running? That's one usual cause for this error menssage.

Comment: I closed the file and it is not shown in Task Manager

Comment: Disable your antivirus. If it is not the one that comes with the OS.

Comment: ***Someone had the same error before?*** Yes the reason will most likely be either of the first 2 comments. Other things that can interfere is using the Run as administrator mode one the previous time.

Comment: In which way the antivirus can be the cause of this error?

Comment: An AV can keep the file open for an extended period of time putting the executable into a sandbox to test it for malicious behavior. I know that aVast and others do this. During this test it may not show up in taskmanager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this error already many times. Though your `myfile.exe` is not shown in TaskManager, It is present in background yet. If you open the `cmd` as administator and type:

> **tasklist | FIND "myfile.exe"**

You can see your process running.

So at this point type the command:

> **taskkill /IM myfile.exe /F**

in order to force the process kill.

Now, if you try to compile your project again, you'll see the compiler is ok and the error is resolved.

Surely it's possible that this error will occur again, so I suggest you to create a `.bat` file that run the kill command, so you can resolve the problem quickly.

Comment: This is not true on my Win11 system:  tasklist does not show my exe as running, and rejects the kill command;  Sysinternals handle does not find any associated handles.  I can delete the file without invoking admin privileges.  It is something else, maybe a linker configuration issue?

Comment: It is a filesystem indexing issue: excluding the build directory from indexing -- both by Windows and by Everything -- fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

regarding:  LNK1168

Microsoft has a web page dedicated to this error:

[LNK1168](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1168?view=msvc-160)

The first thing on the linked page is:

```
The linker can’t write to filename.
```

The rest of the page discusses the details of why the linker cannot write to the file.

Comment: he didn't want why? he wanted how to resolve.